# Duda con Cliente-Servidor en Python

Tags: python, socket

queria preguntar si alguien sabe porque el cliente entra, pero cuando quiero escribir no me deja y se queda como colgado, es porque tengo que cerrar el hilo, o hay algun problema de codigo? Gracias de antemano.

```
import socket
import threading

nombre = input("Escoja su nombre: ")

cliente = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8000))

def recibir():
    while True:
        try:
            mensaje = cliente.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if mensaje == 'NICK':
                cliente.send(nombre.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(mensaje)

        except:
            print("Ha ocurrido un error!")
            cliente.close()
            break

def escribir():
    while True:
        mensaje = f'{nombre}: {input("")}'
        cliente.send(mensaje.encode('ascii'))


recibir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=recibir())
recibir_hilo.start()

escribir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=escribir())
escribir_hilo.start()
```

Comment: Tienes mal creado el hilo. En el parámetro `target` tienes que pasar **la referencia** a la función que debe ejecutarse dentro del hilo. Es decir, `target=recibir`, sin los paréntesis finales. Con esos paréntesis, `recibir()`, estarás invocando a esa función en el hilo actual ( y teóricamente pasando como `target` el valor retornado por esa función). No es lo que quieres hacer aqui. No he mirado si el resto está bien, pero de momento eso causaría que no se lance esa función en otro hilo, y que no se pueda continuar por la línea siguiente hasta que `recibir()` haya retornado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportacion, ese era el fallo, de nuevo, muchas gracias