# Enviar/recibir en un socket en Python

Tags: python, socket

Estoy intentando establecer una conexión entre un servidor daemon y otro programa a través de el socket 4533.
Para ello, me estoy basando en un código de otra duda ([Duda con Cliente-Servidor en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/417164/duda-con-cliente-servidor-en-python)). Parece que la conexión se establece correctamente pero sin embargo, no se por qué, solo ejecuta una de cada dos órdenes. Creo que el error viene en la parte en la que pide el nombre de usuario, pero no he sabido como quitarlo y reemplazarlo por uno que solo me pida introducir las órdenes que deseo.

```
import socket
import threading

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 4533))
nombre = input("Buenos días")

def recibir():
    while True:
        try:
            mensaje = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if mensaje == 'NICK':
                client.send(nombre.encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(mensaje)

        except:
            print("Ha ocurrido un error!")
            client.close()
            break

def escribir():
    while True:
        mensaje = f'{nombre}: {input("")}'
        client.send(mensaje.encode('ascii'))


recibir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=recibir)
recibir_hilo.start()

escribir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=escribir())
escribir_hilo.start()
```

Este es el código.
Otra funcionalidad que quería añadirle es la de enviar un mensaje tipo "quit" o "esc" p.e. que cerrase la conexión, pero soy nuevo en Python y no tengo bastante soltura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay un error en la línea:

```
escribir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=escribir())
```

Estas pasando el resultado de la función `escribir`; lo que debe pasar es la función misma (sacar los paréntesis):

```
escribir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=escribir)
```

Aparte de esos, ajustes menores para terminar adecuadamente las líneas, dejan el programa así:

```
import socket
import threading

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 4533))
nombre = input("Buenos días: ")

def recibir():
    while True:
        try:
            mensaje = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii').strip()
            if mensaje == 'NICK':
                client.send(f"{nombre}\n".encode('ascii'))
            else:
                print(mensaje)
        except:
            print("Ha ocurrido un error!")
            client.close()
            break

def escribir():
    while True:
        mensaje = f'{nombre}: {input("")}\n'
        client.send(mensaje.encode('ascii'))


recibir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=recibir)
recibir_hilo.start()

escribir_hilo = threading.Thread(target=escribir)
escribir_hilo.start()
```

Comment: Buenas, he intentado el código que has sugerido pero no me está funcionando. Se me bloquea y me da el error Bad address (C:\ci\zeromq_1602704446950\work\src\fq.cpp:87)